# Checking region membership in a polygon defined by complex roots

Tags: plotting, functions, complex, regions

I want to define a function that returns `True` if a complex number $z$ is in complex set $\Omega $ which is the pentagon with vertices located at the fifth roots of unity, i.e. $\left\{ 1,\xi,\xi^{2},\xi^{3},\xi^{4}\right\} $ where $\xi=e^{2\pi i/5}$.
Can anyone help me with code or a reference?

I would also like to plot these roots on the complex plane. Any other suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[pts,reg,test,randompts];
pts = Table[Exp[2 k*π*I/5], {k, 0, 4}];
reg = Polygon[ReIm[pts]];
test[z_] = RegionMember[reg]@ReIm@z;
randompts = RandomComplex[1 + I, 5];
test /@randompts
```

```
ComplexListPlot[{pts, randompts}, Epilog -> {{Opacity[.1], reg}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, {AbsolutePointSize[10], Red}}]
```

[image]

- distinguish the color of the point if the random point inside or outside of the region.

```
ComplexListPlot[{pts, 
  If[test[#], Style[#, Red], Style[#, Blue]] & /@ randompts}, 
 Epilog -> {{Opacity[.1], reg}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, {AbsolutePointSize[10], Red}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you also know How can I plot the random number?

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1];
roots = Solve[z^5 == 1, Complexes]
reg = ConvexHullRegion[z /. roots // ReIm]
r1 = Rectangle[{-1.5, -1.5}, {1.5, 1.5}];
RegionQ /@ {reg, r1}
randomPts = RandomPoint[r1, 30]; (*inside a rectangular region*)
ptsInsideRegion = Select[randomPts, RegionMember[reg, #] &];
ptsOutsideRegion = Select[randomPts, ! RegionMember[reg, #] &];

Show[
 RegionPlot[reg
  , PlotStyle -> Directive[{Opacity[0.3], Cyan, reg}]
  , PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[
     {Red, Black, Orange, Cyan, Gray}
     , {"Roots", "Outside", "Inside", "Region", "Rectangle"}]
    , {1.05, 0.5}
    ]
  ],
 ComplexListPlot[z /. roots,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[8], Red]]
 , Epilog -> {
   {Opacity[0.1], r1}
   , AbsolutePointSize[5], Black
   , Point@ptsOutsideRegion
   , AbsolutePointSize[5], Orange
   , Point@ptsInsideRegion
   }
 , Axes -> True
 , GridLines -> Automatic
 , GridLinesStyle -> {{Dotted, Gray}, {Dotted, Gray}}
 , PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
 ]
```

[image]